# why support non js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility, standards

lets face it, everyone uses facebook... - in reality surely everyone has js enabled... why does it seem like you should support the few(if any) without js?

Comment: it's not just people that don't have it, it's people that disable it because they're paranoid little monkies that want to make our lives hell.

Comment: but do people actually disable it? from the people I know who might get scared about these things - they would have no idea how to disable it...

Comment: @Mark s/paranoid/intelligent/  @davivid: I disable and enable it via whitelist.  Trusted sites I view with JS.  Untrusted sites do not get access to JS.

Comment: @davivid I disable it selectively via NoScript and then whitelist those I deem worthy (paranoid monkey checking in)

Comment: Also on some older model cell phones, they just simply can't run JS.

Comment: interesting... i didn't realise people where so careful - from my experience I've never had an issue...maybe the odd pop up here and there - im all over the place...but never even considered i may need to turn off

Comment: Ask the teacher who got fired from her job because her classroom computer suddenly vomited forth dozens of pornographic pop-ups if perhaps turning off JavaScript might be a good idea.

Comment: @JUST I would ask, I guess, were there any support for that anecdote and the same thing could not happen with JavaScript turned off.

Comment: @Alex JL: It took me under two minutes to find support for this anecdote: http://blogs.courant.com/rick_green/2008/11/connecticut-drops-felony-charg.html  Google is your friend.

Comment: @JUST that's great, nice work. I don't think this really has much to do with whether I will continue to browse with JavaScript enabled. Perhaps if I was employed by an incompetent, confused school district and was giving a presentation to a group of students, however, I might choose to be careful.

Answer (score 9):

I think it completely depends on your target audience.  The main reason that standards are in place is to allow web developers to target everyone, regardless of their browser/operating device.  Yes, most people using a computer or modern phone are going to be able to run JavaScript.  So you can not worry about non-js browsers and get away with it.

But, at least in the USA, there is a focus on accessibility for people with disabilities.  Screen readers for the blind, computer data entry for those who type with something other than a keyboard, and other ways of browsing for the disabled means that web developers need to be aware of non-traditional users.  There are some good guidelines on the [ADA's website](http://www.ada.gov/pcatoolkit/chap5toolkit.htm) that explain what to watch out for.

So it all depends on how accessible you want your website to be and how much you care about including everyone regardless of their mode of browsing.

Comment: @Peter Jacoby - Wow. Why don't you just steal the thoughts out of my mind! :P

Comment: surely though anything that is rendered on screen is accessible by modern screen readers?

Comment: BTW: There's a pretty important group of "disabled" users that everybody likes to forget: search engine bots. They don't have JavaScript, they are incredibly stupid, they don't have spatial awareness, only structural (i.e. they don't uderstand that two paragraphs rendered next to each other using `<table>` s are actually related), they are color-blind and deaf and incapable of recognizing pictures.

Comment: @Jorg: I'm trying to make smarter bots that take into consideration 'spatial awareness'... it's not easy.

Comment: @Mark: something like an AI screen scraper? Sounds awesome! Not holding my breath, though ...

Comment: @Jorg: Haha.. don't. Naw, one app is an image downloader that needs to find *the* image on image hosting sites..so it might be surrounded by smaller irrelevant images.. so I need to find "the big centered one", another app is for filling out forms and it needs to look at nearby labels and text to figure out what the content is supposed to be. A mining tool is next on the list... don't hold your breath though.. nothing I do ever gets done :D

Answer (score 3):

Some corporations require that it be turned off.

No one has a hard number for how many people do turn it off.  I read somewhere between 0-10%.

You support the few when you can't afford to alienate that X% of your client base.  It's not that hard to do, but the benefit could be important.  Why not?

Comment: Its not hard to do if you build your site rather conventionally.  But look at something like Gmail....they finally supported non-js clients, but only after a year or so post-launch.  And even then, the only reason they could justify it was because they had so many users.  I imagine it took a huge amount of effort to support non-js browsers....almost total rewrite.

Comment: The OP gave no indication as to whether it's a conventional or GMAIL site.

Comment: Yeha... it really depends on the site. I'm currently working on a website where I have drop-downs that can list 1000s of items... I need to filter that list using JS/Ajax or it would take forever to load... how do you do that without JS? You can't.

Comment: @duffymo: I understand that, my point was that blanket statements like "it's not that hard to do" are not always true.  I know that for the stuff I do, I have no desire to waste my time making an alternative version of the site for non-js.  So I answered your question "Why not?", for me, anyway....that's all.

Comment: It's your choice, rob.  The other key phrase that you aren't missing is assessing the risk you take.  If you decide that it's small, then ignore non-JS and sleep at night.  You don't need the approval of Stackoverflow.com to write your app that way.

Comment: @Mark - the way to filter a list with 1000s of items without JS is to do it properly on the server side and not send them to the client in the first place.

Comment: @duffymo: How??? They're filtered based on a previous input. You'd have to do a stupid page-by-page wizard to filter it server-side.

Comment: Sory, I don't recall seeing complete requirements.  You'd send the previous input to the server and ask it to create the list contents for you.  Yes, it would mean a round trip to the server.

Comment: HAHAHAHA, it's 0.25% up to 1%, and at the very most 2%.... I think i'll take my chances by not making a whole new version for the people who don't use a good browser like Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

The only compelling reason for supporting non-JS-enabled browsers I can think of is if you have clients who are paying you to do that. End of story.

Comment: Your lack of imagination does not an argument make.

Comment: I'm stating an opinion, not trying to argue with someone who thinks he's always right. But go ahead and make a personal attack anyway.

Comment: Your client doesn't even know the difference. I just made a site, and I made it JS-only because my client didn't specify, and he didn't ask me to make it non-JS enabled. A while later, I get a call, "It doesn't work... feature XXX isn't loading".. "Oh..yeah.. that's because it requires JS". Letting your client decide isn't a good way to decide because he doesn't know any better, and eventually it'll bite you in the ass when he figures it out.

Answer (score 3):

I think that when it comes down it, it it really depends on your target audience. If you know that your target audience is most likely to have JavaScript enabled, then so be it.

I have a situation at work, however, where I know that some of the people I develop for may be using old browsers and whether I like it or not, I cannot force them to upgrade.

You also want to consider allowing your site to be accessible to all platforms and browsers and this includes audio and text based browsers. It's possible that your site will be inaccessible to people with disabilities.

Whether that's important enough for you to develop a non-JavaScript version of your site, that's up to you.

Comment: I would like it to be accessible to all(disability wise), and it was my understanding that as long as your careful as to what is rendered on screen, modern screen readers etc should have no problem?

Comment: @davivid - That's important too but not everything. For example, you need to be considerate about putting appropriate `alt=""` attributes in images so that if a text reader or screen reader comes across it, it'll know (and more importantly the USER will know) what it is. Check out [this site](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag.php) for some more info on web accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're really supporting non js users, you're supporting unknown methods.  Coding fall back links and such is good practice.  It helps search engines, and web scrapers, and primitive mobile devices that don't support js yet, or older section 508 browser.  I myself would tend to agree that the web nowadays is pretty useless without js but you should still do what you can to support non js in at very least fall back mode.

Comment: I would def support all SEO practices include #!, for any page it makes sense for. although not sure why I would support any web scraper?!

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is fragile. There are lots of things that can make it break, from bugs in browsers you've not tested (especially mobile browsers), to browser extensions fiddling with your code, to dodgy ‘internet security’ apps blocking parts of your code. If your site works without JavaScript, you don't have to worry so much about that, because it'll likely still function in these circumstances.

JavaScript tends not to interact well with accessibility aids. A site that works without JavaScript will be more likely usable to screen readers and other unusual user agents you may not have bargained for.

And apart from the people who browse with JS off for security/privacy or because they have no choice, there's also a fairly important class of user-agent with no JavaScript support: the spider. Hide all your content so it can't be accessed without JavaScript and you've just lost a friend in Google. Hope you weren't counting on a lot of visitors or anything.

Build a site that works without scripting, and then add the progressive-enhancement JS magic on top. You'll have a site that works for more people, that is likely to have fewer usability problems(*), and is friendlier to SEO. It's all-round win, unless (a) you've got a task that due to its nature requires scripting, or (b) you're just lazy.

(*: eg, links that you can middle-click but which just open into a JS error, unbookmarkable subpages, UI elements that don't respond to keyboard interaction, broken navigation... you can write JS in a clean way to minimise these problems. But most people don't.)

Comment: good points, seo wise im pretty clued up, but development and deadlines is a whole new field. Surely though with #! and good on-screen semantic structured content, these kind of things are getting less relevant each day?

Comment: Sure. But if you've got proper hashnav and `#!` pointers to real documents, where you spit out on the server-side the same as what the client-side script would have produced, then you've already done the hard part of making the site accessible without JS. Having done that, you might as well get the usability and accessibility advantages of that by providing real HTML links to the server-side documents, that work for non-JS agents, open-in-new-window, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* to support it. If you think you won't lose any noticeable traffic by offering a JS-only site, offer a JS-only site. But if you think you'll see more traffic and perhaps make more sales, considering a non-JS site is not a bad idea.

Also make the distinction between a full-JS site and just a few JS-addons that make forms a bit easier to use. In many cases you can easily offer the exact same functionality apart from those few JS niceties.

And always make sure to add the necessary checks/validations in the *backend*, since you can't be sure someone uses JS and it can thus be handles by the *frontend*.

Answer (score 1):

*lets face it, everyone uses facebook... - in reality surely everyone has js enabled... why does it does it seem like you should support the few(if any) without js?*

Seems I'm not everyone. I have JS disabled per default. I'm not paranoid, but I dont like viagra-promotion running trough my browser and similar toys(maybe I'm not the only one).

But it's not a problem, if I visit a page that seems to be interesting to me, I can turn it on with one click. That's the point for me regarding to your question: if you forget users without javascript like me, they may not be able to see if your page could be interesting.

So the question is really simple to answer: **if you don't want to lose users because of disabled JS**, you support them too.

Also keep in mind: if you have a business on your page, you not only lose users, you lose earnings.

Comment: but this is the point - you have it turned off for a reason, and you know how to turn it on if you want to... the average joe doesn't even know what js is..

Comment: So why let the "average" wait on closed doors? It often is not hard to have a basic accessibility without JS.

Comment: There are not only popups in the world of advertisements. I talk about layer-ads, funny flash-movies that make some noise while I listen to the radio etc.  However, your downvote to my answer shows that you don't understand anything, the question is not about why I have JS disabled, the question is about why support users with js disabled, and my answer was: **if you don't want to lose users because of disabled JS**

Comment: To clarify what I'm talking about: see the statistic linked by Grillz, 2% inside the US have JS disabled. Imagine a online-shop in the US with 1million $ yearly sales. Would you suggest them not to support users with JS disabled and give away $20.000 ??

Answer (score 1):

The Yahoo Dev Network did some checking on this, and depending on how many users you have visiting your site it can be a significant number of people.

http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/

Comment: There's a pretty interesting comment on that post about being careful with selection bias. To paraphrase: refusing to make your site work with JS disabled on the argument that your stats indicate that the number of users with JS disabled is vanishingly small is pretty stupid. Why? Well, if your site doesn't work without JS, users who have JS disabled won't visit your site and instead go to your competitors, so the fact that on a site that cannot be visited without JS there are no visitors without JS isn't terribly surprising. It's basically a circular argument.

Answer (score 1):

Many mobile devices don't support JS at all yet. Even new-ish Blackberries have horrible browsers that either have javascript carrier-disabled, or its just so bad that you wouldn't want it turned on anyway.

Comment: that's such a small percentage though. If people want to go to a website, if their phones suck at web, they'll prefer the computer. I don't browse the web on my 4.5 inch android phone too much, if there's a site I really want to check out, i go to the computer. Most phones support javascript. The percentage of ACTIVE phones that people want to browse the web on, that don't have javascript... has gotta be a VERY VERY low percentage, so low, I don't think this specific reason is valid anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Robustness. Bugs in your Javascript code tend to become low severity issues instead of high severity issues.

Answer (score 0):

Because JavaScript is an easy to learn language and really simple to implement in webpages and starting writing scripts by your own, and because of this there are horribly bad written scripts and plugins out there that users put on their websites causing horribly bugs, slowdowns, choppy and almost impossible user experience, lag and coding horrors among the other things.

Also, mobile devices users may want to have it disabled to save bandwidth (money) and CPU usage (battery). Many mobile browsers have really bad JS support and so it's useless anyway.